# ASP.NET Dynamic Data does not render additional properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a case where I need to add properties to my generated model. Basically what I've done is the following:

- Generate the entity model from an existing database
- Created a partial class which has the same name and namespace as one of my entity models
- I added a property inside the partial class and decorated it with `[ScaffoldColumn(true)]`:

  ```
  [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
  public String EnglishText
  {
      get
      {
          return this._resourceHelper.GetValue(this.Code, 4, 1);
      }
      set
      {
          this._resourceHelper.SetValue(value, this.Code, 4, 1);
      }
  }
  ```

But for some reason, this property is not being rendered on the view. Do I need to do anything else in order to tell DD to render the property?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the property in metadata like you do for other properties.

```
public class FooMetadata
{
    // other columns in table then your added property
    [Display(Name = "Text")]
    public object EnglishText { get; set; }
}
```